# Uncaught TypeError: $(...).datepicker error on datepicker

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap-3, datepicker

So I want to have a text field where a calendar pops up and a user can easily pick a date. However, I am getting `Uncaught TypeError: $(...).datepicker is not a function` error when I try to debug why the calendar is not popping out.

Below is my code, kindly advice. I have searched even on this forum but can not solve it.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <title>date</title>

    <!-- Fonts -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" integrity="sha384-XdYbMnZ/QjLh6iI4ogqCTaIjrFk87ip+ekIjefZch0Y+PvJ8CDYtEs1ipDmPorQ+" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:100,300,400,700">

    <!-- Styles -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">
    
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.6.3/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.2/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">

    
</head>
<body id="app-layout"  class="fuelux">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-static-top">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar-header">

                <!-- Collapsed Hamburger -->
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#app-navbar-collapse">
                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle Navigation</span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
                <!-- Branding Image -->
            </div>

            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="app-navbar-collapse">
                <!-- Left Side Of Navbar -->
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li><a href="#" class="log" style="color:white">Sisimsha Booking Engine</a></li>
                </ul>             
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>

<div class="container">
<div class="row">
<div class="col-lg-5 col-sm-5 col-xs-12">
 <div class="form-group{{ $errors->has('date') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
    <label for="Event Date">Event Date</label>
    <input name="date" type="text" class="form-control" id='datepicker'  placeholder="Date" 
 </div>  
</div>
</div>
<div class="row">
<div class="col-lg-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
<a href="coupleDetails" class="btn btn-primary"> Back </a>
<input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary pull-right" value="Next">
</div>
</div>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
</div>

    <!-- JavaScripts -->
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.3/jquery.min.js" integrity="sha384-I6F5OKECLVtK/BL+8iSLDEHowSAfUo76ZL9+kGAgTRdiByINKJaqTPH/QVNS1VDb" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-0mSbJDEHialfmuBBQP6A4Qrprq5OVfW37PRR3j5ELqxss1yVqOtnepnHVP9aJ7xS" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
   <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
     <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script> 
 <script>
  $(function() {
    $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker().datepicker( "option", "dateFormat", 'yy-mm-dd');
  });
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Kindly, would anyone let me know that which I am doing wrong? 
Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

You included three different copies of jQuery.js, including one *after* the jQuery-ui.js include so when you use `$` you'll be getting the third instance with no jQuery-UI.

Your code works if you remove the second and third of those includes, as you can see if you expand and run this snippet:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <title>date</title>

    <!-- Fonts -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" integrity="sha384-XdYbMnZ/QjLh6iI4ogqCTaIjrFk87ip+ekIjefZch0Y+PvJ8CDYtEs1ipDmPorQ+" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:100,300,400,700">

    <!-- Styles -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">
    
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.6.3/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.2/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">

    
</head>
<body id="app-layout"  class="fuelux">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-static-top">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar-header">

                <!-- Collapsed Hamburger -->
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#app-navbar-collapse">
                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle Navigation</span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
                <!-- Branding Image -->
            </div>

            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="app-navbar-collapse">
                <!-- Left Side Of Navbar -->
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li><a href="#" class="log" style="color:white">Sisimsha Booking Engine</a></li>
                </ul>             
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>

<div class="container">
<div class="row">
<div class="col-lg-5 col-sm-5 col-xs-12">
 <div class="form-group{{ $errors->has('date') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
    <label for="Event Date">Event Date</label>
    <input name="date" type="text" class="form-control" id='datepicker'  placeholder="Date" 
 </div>  
</div>
</div>
<div class="row">
<div class="col-lg-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
<a href="coupleDetails" class="btn btn-primary"> Back </a>
<input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary pull-right" value="Next">
</div>
</div>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
</div>

    <!-- JavaScripts -->
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.3/jquery.min.js" integrity="sha384-I6F5OKECLVtK/BL+8iSLDEHowSAfUo76ZL9+kGAgTRdiByINKJaqTPH/QVNS1VDb" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-0mSbJDEHialfmuBBQP6A4Qrprq5OVfW37PRR3j5ELqxss1yVqOtnepnHVP9aJ7xS" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script> 
 <script>
  $(function() {
    $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker().datepicker( "option", "dateFormat", 'yy-mm-dd');
  });
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You're loading jQuery not one, but *three* times. jQuery UI is loaded after the second instance, but before the third, so it's attached to the second instance. However, since the third instance is loaded last, its `$` variable, which does not have jQuery UI attached, shadows the others, so you can't use jQuery UI.

The solution is simple: just remove two of the jQuery versions, and your code should work fine!

(You also included Bootstrap *twice*; you need to be more careful about not including your scripts and stylesheets more than once, since they may interfere with each other in unexpected ways.)

Answer (score 0):

Please use this running code.i hope it's help you.

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function(){
        jQuery('#datetimepicker').datepicker();
    })
</script>

<input id="datetimepicker" type="text">
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer, otherwise it's difficult to understand what's the difference between it and the code in the question.

Comment: What happened to the OP's date format option? Why did you change the element ID? Why didn't the OP's code work?

Comment: thanks @ Frxstrem  it is very simle textbox id name is  datetimepicker  and   it pass in jquery method.

Comment: @nnnnnn  you use for formating  $("#datepicker").datepicker({ dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd" }).val()